# QGIS cannot open layer properties

Tags: qgis, layers

I'm trying to open (vector) layer properties in QGIS 2.2.0 and 2.4.0 (Windows 8.1) and nothing is happening. The application freezes and not responding at all (requires cntrl+alt+delete to close).
I have tried:

1. Reinstalling the app
2. Deleting .qgis2 folder
3. CLose (and open) the Layers panel
4. Removing all the plugins

...nothing helps.
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Does it happen with a particular dataset only or with all datasets?

Comment: Is your computer 32-bit/64-bit and did you select the relevant installer?

Comment: What data source has the layer: shapefile, Raster file, WMS, Postgis?

Comment: It happens with all vector datasets.

Comment: My computer is 64-bit and I did select the relevant installer.

Comment: Layer data source is shapefile (vector). There is no problem with rasters.

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete the QGIS folder in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming`.
For me that solved the issue